# Finding regular expression in list of files

Tags: linux, perl, sed, grep, csh

I have several header files in a directory with the format imageN.hd where N is some integer. Only one of these header files contains the text 'trans'. What I am trying to do is find which image contains this expression using csh (I need to use csh for this purpose - although I can call sed or perl one-liners) and show the corresponding image.
`show iN`

Here is my initial unsophisticated approach which does not work.

```
#find number of header files in directory
set n_images = `ls | grep 'image[0-9]*.hd' | wc -l`
foreach N(`seq 1 n_images`)
if (`more image$N{.hd} | grep -i 'trans`) then
show i$N
sc c image   #this command uses an alias to set the displayed image as current within the script
endif
end
```

I'm not sure what is wrong with the above commands but it does not return the correct image number.

Also I'm sure there is a more elegant one line perl or sed solution but I am fairly unfamiliar with both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
show `grep -l trans image[0-9]*.hd | sed 's/image/i/`
```

Comment: Excellent solution. I need the -i flag and I can extract the number from a basic sed